# Downloading Selenium Chrome Webdriver not working macos

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with python. I'm pretty sure my browser updated when I restarted my computer. When I ran my code it gave me an error saying the driver was not up to date with the browser. I went [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) to download the most recent version. I am using MacOS BTW. When I launched the executable it just gets stuck on "ChromeDriver was started successfully."
I would launch the executable and leave it there for 10 minutes and it would just get stuck on this. How can I fix this?
[image: The terminal]

Comment: How do you launch the driver? What code are you executing until launch and what code do you have after?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download the same version of the driver as your chrome version.

To check your chrome version:
[image: img1]

Click on the 3 dots in the top right corner.

[image: img2]
Hover over the help tab and click on **About Google Chrome**.

[image: img3]
You will be able to see your chrome version. Since my chrome version is 88, I would have to download driver version 88.

[image: img4]

If you just updated chrome, your version might be 89.

Comment: I'm downloading the same version of the driver as the browser. It just doesn't finish executing the script. It's stuck on "ChromeDriver was started successfully."

Comment: hmm, can you attach a screenshot to the question?

Comment: I attached a screen shot in my post. I'm using MacOS BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I used to just run the executable but I guess that doesn't work? So according to [this post](https://www.edureka.co/community/52315/how-to-setup-chrome-driver-with-selenium-on-macos) you have to move it manually to the usr/local/bin folder. Going there I deleted the old chromedriver and replaced it with the new one.

Comment: yeah, u would have to put it inside a folder that can be accessed by python.